# Sencha Touch 2 Offline Caching with JsonP Proxy

Tags: list, caching, proxy, jsonp, extjs

Assuming that I have followed the Sencha Touch 2 Getting Started tutorial, and have a list populated by JsonP proxy data- how do I go about making cached data appear if the user is offline? Currently, the list is simply not displayed if there is no internet connection.

In the video tutorial, Ed briefly mentions that this can "easily be done" but did not provide a reference to where I might find this in the Sencha documentation.

Below is an example of my store object:

```
Ext.define('test.store.NewsListStore', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['test.model.NewsListModel', 'Ext.data.Request'],
config : {
    model : 'test.model.NewsListModel',
    storeId : 'news-list-store',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url : 'http://example.com/jsonp',
    config : {
        noCache: false
    }
   },
    grouper : {
        groupFn : function(record) {
            var unix_timestamp = parseInt(record.get("entry_date"));
            var date = new Date( unix_timestamp*1000 );
            return Ext.Date.format(date, 'F');
        }
    },
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial about taking a [Sencha Touch app offline](http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/) - it's not Sencha Touch 2 but it might point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you can follow with localstorage:

http://www.robertkehoe.com/2012/11/sencha-touch-2-localstorage-example/

It uses Sencha Touch 2